# Rendering animation not working

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, fluid-simulation

I have made a simple fluid simulation in Blender 2.8 and whenever I render it it doesn't work.
First I tried rendering it as a png but that just produced 4 images and no video or animation. Then I tried rendering it as a FFmpeg video and when I try to play it all I see is a black screen. Can anyone help me?

[image] [image]

Comment: You say it only rendered 4 images? how many frames are in your animation? if you tried to render a MP4 with only 4 frames then that would only be 1/6th of a second-long video.

Answer (score 0):

You have to render it as a .png image sequence in your preferred file, and then go to the video editing section of Blender, browse for the frames, select them then add them, and then sequence the pictures into a video.